# ASP.NET Table Adapter date overflow while update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am creating an front end to the AdventureWorks sample database.

I am trying to update a row in HumanResources.Department.

I am using a DataSet with Table Adapter for this table.

Inserting and updating a row causes issues :

```cs
 public Department InserDepartment(Department department) 
 {
    try 
    {
       department.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
       Int32 id = departmentTableAdapter.Insert(department.Name, department.GroupName, department.ModifiedDate);   
       return new Department();
     }
     catch (Exception ex) 
     {
        return new Department();
     }
 }
```

```cs
public Department UpdateDepratment(Department department) 
{
   try
   {
      HumanResourcesDataSet.DepartmentDataTable tblDepartments = departmentTableAdapter.GetDataByDepartmentId(department.DepartmentID);
      HumanResourcesDataSet.DepartmentRow departmentRow = tblDepartments[0];
      departmentRow.Name = department.Name;
      department.GroupName = department.GroupName;
      department.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
      departmentTableAdapter.Update(tblDepartments);
      department = GetDepartment(department.DepartmentID);
      return department;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       // TBD
   }
}
```

Following exception occures:

> The fractional part of the provided time value overflows the scale of the corresponding SQL Server parameter or column. Increase bScale in DBPARAMBINDINFO or column scale to correct this error.

The issue is caused by following line in my update method:

```cs
department.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

The data set accepts a DateTime class for this column, the database definition is a datetime, not null.

I have implemented datetime columns in other databases, and never had this issue.

What am I missing, that causes the issue?
Where should I search for solution to this issue?

Comment: What is the  datatype of `ModifiedDate`?

Comment: @Larnu it's a DateTime in C#, and datetime in SQL

Comment: What does DateTime.Now return, format wise?

Comment: @Cedersved something like this 29/12/2020 14:46:44

Comment: Try it with: DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

Comment: i am using an TableAdapter Method for the insert. I do not format the date time into string before inserting. I am setting the properties to the table row, and then inserting that row via TableAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

So, i did not entirely found a cause and a proper solution for this issue. I added new stored procedure for an update on the table in question, which seems to solve some issues. The issue is somewhere in my data provider (System.Data.OleDb) and my SQL server.

The server is a SQL - Express. I imported the database from a .bak file.

In the stored procedure, i set `ModifiedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and pass the other values as param.

My assumption is, that my update interfered with folloving SQL script

[ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Department_ModifiedDate] DEFAULT (GETDATE())

I don't really want to tinker wiht the structure of the database and change a default, since i don't understand the database that well so far.

I can't really ignore the column as well, since I can update only an entire row with my table adapter, which includes the date that is set in my DataRow instance.